# Custom time in chart.js streaming plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

I'm struggling with changing default realtime from streaming plugin for chart.js. Only what I need is "moving chart" which refresh data every 1 second and display my data on X and Y axis.

[My chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdOIZ.png)

Ultimately I want to display the simulation time from the simulink model in seconds. I have the actual time in my vuex so just need to somehow convert the realtime to time from the simulation.

```
    simuTime() {
        return this.$store.getters.simulationTime
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const ctx = this.$refs.mychart
    const data = {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "Mains_1_Voltage",
                data: [],
                backgroundColor: "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
                borderColor: "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
                borderWidth: 1,
            },
            {
                label: "Mains_1_Frequency",
                data: [],
                backgroundColor: "rgba(248, 109, 181, 1)",
                borderColor: "rgba(163, 109, 181, 1)",
                borderWidth: 1,
            },
        ],
    }
    var config = {
        type: "line",
        data: data,
        options: {
            scales: {
                x: {
                    type: 'realtime',
                    realtime: {
                        delay: 1000,
                        onRefresh: chart => {
                            chart.data.datasets[0].data.push({
                                //this doesn't work after changing from Date.now()
                                x: this.simuTime,
                                y: this.V1[0].value
                            })
                            chart.data.datasets[1].data.push({
                                //this doesn't work after changing from Date.now()
                                x: this.simuTime,
                                y: this.F1[0].value
                            })
                        }
                    }
                },
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                },
            },
        },
    }
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
    myChart
    this.simu_time_interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.$store.dispatch('calculateSimulationTime')
    }, 500);
  },
  beforeUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.simu_time_interval)
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your use case, you would like to have the elapsed time from the start of simulation.

I think the `Date.now()` must be used anyway because the `realtime` scale is anyway a time scale and needs to have a time as x value.
But you can implement the `ticks.callback` in order to show on the chart the elapsed time, instead of the date.

In the below sample, I assumed that the start of simulation is the current time (`Date.now()`).

EDIT: after the thread with @dymek662, the solution is changed a bit.
Main changes in order to address the use case:

1. use ticks.source: 'data'
2. the data have got all the same datetime
3. add "simutime" as additional property of the data of the 1 dataset

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

//lets simulate 'simutime'
let simutime = Math.floor(Math.random(100)*100);
setInterval(() => {
  //i added some random values just to have raising values like in my original simutime from matlab model
  simutime += 3;
}, 500);

const data = {
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Mains_1_Voltage",
      data: [],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
      borderWidth: 1,
    },
    {
      label: "Mains_1_Frequency",
      data: [],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(248, 109, 181, 1)",
      borderColor: "rgba(163, 109, 181, 1)",
      borderWidth: 1,
    }
  ]
};
const config = {
  type: "line",
  data: data,
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          title(items) {
            if (items.length) {
              const item = items[0];
              const {chart, datasetIndex, dataIndex} = item;
              const simutimeData = chart.data.datasets[0].data[dataIndex];
              return 'Simutime: ' + simutimeData.simutime;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'realtime',
        realtime: {
          delay: 1000,
          onRefresh: chart => {
            // get unique time stamp for all data
            const now = Date.now(); 
            // check if the simutime is already stored
            // if yes, set undefined
            const data = chart.data.datasets[0].data.filter(element => element.simutime);
            let simu = simutime;
            if (data.length) {
              const lastData = data[data.length - 1];
              if (lastData.simutime === simu) {
                simu = undefined;
              }
            }
            chart.data.datasets[0].data.push({
              x: now,
              y: Math.random() * 100,
              simutime: simu
            });
            chart.data.datasets[1].data.push({
              x: now,
              y: Math.random() * 100
            });
          }
        },
        ticks: {
          // this forces to use the data for ticks 
          source: 'data',
          callback(value, index, ticks) {
            const tickValue = ticks[index].value;
            if (tickValue) {
              const dataset1Data = this.chart.data.datasets[0].data;
              const data = dataset1Data.filter(element => element.x === tickValue);
              if (data.length) {
                return data[0].simutime;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 100
      },
    },
  },
};
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@3.0.1/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-luxon@1.2.0/dist/chartjs-adapter-luxon.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-streaming@2.0.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-streaming.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, I just tested your solution. I think it will fir in my needs but after implementing your code I still have realtime notation. On the answer I'm putting my actual code. Also I don't understand line const chart = this.chart it's not used anywhere.

Comment: yeah, I forgot to remove that line because not needed. Thank you. Updated my answer as well.

Comment: Nevermind, just found the issue. Needed to move ticks section to X scale object.

Comment: Glad to read that it's working. It's not perfect at 100%. I spent time to find out when to display the first tick ("start").

Comment: So much thanks for your effort. But I have one problem with which I'm still struggling.... I want to show on X axis custom values (it's this time from simulation but this time is not related with real time -> time in simulation can be faster or slower) but for better understanding my problem Is any option to show random numbers on X axis from Math.random() for example? So chart will be moving but it will show values unrelated with time. If I will be possible to do it I will be able to solve my problem. Please let me know if you understand.

Comment: Returning in the last line Math.floor(Math.random(100)*100) is actuall changing their value as they move.

Comment: You can change the logic of "ticks.callback" as you want. Finally it's this callback which is returning the tick to show. Therefore you can return "Math.floor(Math.random(100)*100)" to show a random value, not related to the time. I hope to have understood well your need.

Comment: When I'm returning Math.random every value on the chart is changing value on the move. I need something like: new value (tick i guess) on initialization draws random int and stay with this value till it disappear from chart. Also when i want to return simutime (what is destination of my problem) it changes all the values on the chart. In conlusion is any option to assign value to every single tick? Like callback for only one single tick which is going to display.

Comment: About the initial value, have a look to this codepen: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/zYWXjyx

Comment: The ticks.callback is called for every single tick to show in the chart. Therefore having a simutime (I think a date or?) you can return the value that you want. Maybe you can use the codepen that I have added  with your use case 8and problem).

Comment: Here are my codepen with problem and explanation in comments:

https://codepen.io/dymek662/pen/gOeVbQM

Comment: Having a look to codepen, it's not clear to me what "this.simutime" is. I don't understand if it's an epoch or just an amount of seconds. And when you write "this." which object are you referring to? I was thinking that when the simulate is started we can mark the starting and then set the seconds in every tick.

Comment: I'm writting in the Vue so this is refference to vue data object. It just stores the simulation time in the variable this.simuTime and is updated on the fly. Simulation time is not the same as real time -> 1s simulation time can last 2s (or longer/shorter) in real time and vice versa. Therefore, it would be easiest to assume that simulation time is simply some data that I want to display every second on the X axis. The data on the X-axis might as well be some voltage or frequency, irrelevant. I simply need to display a pair of X and Y values that will move like a real-time graph.

Comment: ok, now sounds more clear. The problem is you can not set the ticks which are calculated automatically, based on the data of dataset. let me think more maybe I can find another way to do that. I was thinking about a dataset with simutimes and another scale but I need time to setup a sample. I hope it's ok for you

Comment: Well, I think now we are on teh good way. See the codepen: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/zYWXjyx I have added also some comments to explain better. 2 main factors probably solved the issue: 1. use ticks.source: 'data' and 2. to have a dataset with the simutimes data. Have a look.

Comment: Again thanks for your effort so much! I think we almost done but when I'm putting simutime (in seconds, or miliseconds) the X axis doesn't show any values. On codepen on top i pasted the similar thing like my simutime values: https://codepen.io/dymek662/pen/QWrLjNY

Comment: Having the simuTime in seconds, you should add the seconds to the starting time in order to have an appropriate epoch. Having a look to your codepen, sounds strange that simuTime can start with simutime = Math.floor(Math.random(100)*100), been a simutime the amount of seconds. Maybe should start from 0.  and it's also strange that being the simutime an amount of seconds, you are updating it every 500ms. I'm updating the codepen with your updates and how to manage simutime as seconds

Comment: I added this random because in my case someone can run the chart when simulation was started before -> so the 0 won't be always starting point. Then I created interval with 500s because the simulation time is not like realtime, in realtime 3 seconds will be f.e equal 20 seconds of the simulation. So the simulation time is just some value not realted with realtime (user can change speed of simulation), it's just value which i need to show on X axis every 1 second. The interval is only imitating my simutime because i cant add it here because the simutime value is getting fetched from my backend.

Comment: Ok, in this case we are trying to use a timeseries scale where X values are not a date time. But we want to show those ticks. Even more complex... let me take time but maybe I've got an idea

Comment: Basically the idea with 3 datasets is good. I think this is what I need. Take a look on the picture (dataset3 is dataset with simutime)  https://imgur.com/a/T8d06Qk

Comment: Correct! I'm testing it before showing you. The streaming plugin is continuing updating the chart and adding data externally (not from plugin) it seems not the best thing and some simu data are not recognize but I think it's solveable.

Comment: Have a look now: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/RwybWpQ The simutime could be whatever value. The data are added to simu dataset by the plugin.

Comment: The dataset 3 (for simutime) is useless, sorry. Reviewed and updated in order to use only 2 datasets. Removed also useless config, like legend. Sounds more simple. https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/RwybWpQ let me know if ok because I think it could be helpful to publish it as answer with the snippet for others who can be interested to the same use case

Comment: You saved my life! Works exactly as I needed. Now I can display time from simulation and other data on X axis instead of realtime and seems to work well. I am very very grateful to you for your time and help. Thank you so much! And I think its great idea to publish snippet as answer.

Comment: Do you think it's helpful to submit an answer with all details shared in the comments?

Comment: I think best way will be if you will create another answer with code from codepen with short explanation, and we can keep this discussion here. It's very specific use case but I think it might be very helpful for someone, because nowhere in the internet is about changing default timeseries.

Comment: I have one last question if you would still like to -> it's possible to change on hover label from realtime time to X value? take a look on the picutre: https://imgur.com/a/3uML9zX

Comment: Yes, you can, by "tooltip.callbacks". There several callbacks, title, body label and footer. If I understood well, i'd like to have the X value (datetime) to simutime. Correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: Added to codepen: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/RwybWpQ

Comment: FYI I have changed my answer adding last version of the codepen.